# Is it always true that if $\sigma(n) + 1$ is divisible by $n$ then $\sigma(n) = 2n - 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Suppose $n$ is a natural number, such that $\sigma(n) + 1$ is divisible by $n$. Is it always true that $\sigma(n) = 2n - 1$?

I checked this for all numbers less than $1000000$ and did not find any counterexample among them. However, any proof of this statement is also unknown to me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "divisible by $n$" instead?

Comment: This seems happen iff $n$ is a power of $2$, which are exactly the only numbers known to have $\sigma(n) = 2n - 1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number.